# Extend Python with C but need to import Time module

Tags: python, python-import, extend

I am trying run my Python script in C program. 
I have studied the Python.org documentation and following the guide the implement extending Python with C, https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

I was able to run some simple Python codes with this setup. 
However, my Python program needs to make use of the time module, i.e. import time, and when I compile, it complains cannot import module time. How can I do the import properly? I am using Python 2.6.

The SystemVerilog code looks like this

```
`timescale 1 ns/1 ns
module top;
      import "DPI-C" context task startPython();
      export "DPI-C" task sv_write;

   // Exported SV task.  Can be called by C,SV or Python using c_write
   task sv_write(input int data,address);
      begin
     $display("sv_write(data = %d, address = %d)",data,address);
      end
   endtask

   initial
     begin
    startPython();
    $display("DONE!!");
     end

endmodule
```

The C code looks like this

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "vpi_user.h"
#include "pythonEmbedded.h"

static PyObject * c_write(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    int address,data;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &data, &address))
      return NULL;
    sv_write(address,data);
    return Py_BuildValue("");
}

static PyMethodDef EmbMethods[] = {
    {"c_write",c_write, METH_VARARGS,"c_write(data,address)"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

DPI_DLLESPEC
int startPython(){
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_InitModule("emb", EmbMethods);
    PyRun_SimpleString("import emb\n"
               "emb.c_write(0,1)\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import time\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is below:

```
# Loading ./pythonEmbedded.so
# run -all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/timemodule.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_ValueError
# sv_write(data =           1, address =           0)
# DONE!!
#  quit -f
# End time: 06:41:05 on Feb 24,2016, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
```

The Makefile to compile the code is below:

```
MTI_HOME = /apps/mentor/questasim
INCLUDE  = $(INCLIBC) -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I$(MTI_HOME)/include
CFLAGS   = -gstabs -Wall -fpic -shared
MTI_GCC  = /apps/mentor/questasim/gcc-4.7.4-linux_x86_64
COMPILER = $(MTI_GCC)/bin/gcc
LIBS     = -lc -lssl -lpthread -lm -ldl -lutil -lpython2.6

sim:    pythonEmbedded.h pythonEmbedded.so
        vsim -64 top -c -sv_lib pythonEmbedded -do "run -all; quit -f"

pythonEmbedded.h: pythonEmbedded.sv
        vlib work
        vlog -64 -sv -dpiheader pythonEmbedded.h pythonEmbedded.sv

pythonEmbedded.sv:

pythonEmbedded.so: pythonEmbedded.c
        $(COMPILER) $< $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post your code, i.e. the relevant Python part, as well as the C program that uses it? Your compiler instructions (makefile?) would also be useful. Otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: In fact, I am following this piece of work, to add on Python embedding. https://andreaslindh.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/embedpythoninverilogexample/  

When I want to add  PyRun_SimpleString("import time\n");
it won't work

Comment: Sure, I understand. It really increases your chance of getting help here if your question is complete and doesn't require people to follow external links. Ideally, you want your question to include a *minimum working example* of code that produces the errors you're getting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the code in my Post, sorry, newbie here...

Comment: Great, thanks! This is *exactly* what a good question should look like. Good questions are far more likely to yield a helpful answer quicker. The only thing missing is the error trace that you get (`complains cannot find module time`).

Comment: Are you sure the failure is on the `import time`? If you comment that out of your C code, do you still get that error?

Comment: Try to get a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You showed some code, but there are a LOT of external requirements and I am unable to guess what is the Verilog code doing here (also: check your question tags, maybe you forgot to add some relevant additional ones?)

Comment: Without the line "import time", it doesn't report any error. For instance, if I do import os or import sys, it has no problem.